# angularjs $q then() > catch() > then(), cancel execution of last then()

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have the following code (simplified for brevity):

```
var makeRequest = function (method, url, query, data) {
    var request = {
        method: method,
        url: url,
        params: query || {},
        paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
        data: data || {},
        timeout: 10000
    };

    if (method === 'POST' || method === 'PUT') {
        request.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' };
    }

    return $http(request)
        .then(function (response) {
            response = normalizeResponse(response.data); // ensures {result, data, msg}

            if (!response.result) {
                throw {data: response};
            }

            return response;
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            Notify('error', response.data.msg);
        });
};
```

Calling it looks like this:

```
makeRequest('GET', '/user').then(function (response) {
    console.log('user=', response.data);
});
```

This works fine for successful requests, but as soon as I make a failing request, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`, since `catch()` does not (and should not) return anything, but the second `then()` promise is still executed.

I want `catch()` to be the last thing that executes, and any further `then()` calls to not execute if the request itself fails. The catch block is universal across the system, so it doesn't make sense to copy-paste it everywhere, it's not DRY. Is it possible or do I have to do some kind of dirty hacks for this?

Note: I still want the promise chaining to be available if request succeeds.

Comment: I think you're wrongfully assuming that to reach your `catch` you must first reach your `then`. You might reach your catch if the original `$http(request)` fails to successfully resolve the promise.

Comment: Wrong. `catch()` is executed on a normal 404 and it skips the first `then()`, but it does call the second `then()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A catch block "rescues" the promise and allows `.then` calls later on to proceed as normal.  If you want to avoid this behavior, just re-throw the error in the catch block.

```
.catch(function (response) {
  Notify('error', response.data.msg);
  throw response.data.msg;
});
```